# no download for 13.04 raring ringtail

Tags: 13.04

I have 13.04 Raring Ringtail OS, installed from USB
but to install other vender software like google earth, it requests the installation CD/DVD, which I never had, but now need. The USB installation media is long gone, so how do I download and cut a CD with 13.04 if the download does not exist?

Comment: still getting the following message from attempt to install: CD/DVD 'Ubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130424)' is required    My Ubuntu Software Center has no edit area at all, so this is not possible, can it be done with ¨Terminal¨?

Comment: It actually has... but it's a bit hidden since Unity. When you open Ubuntu Software Center, and with it in the foreground, place your mouse cursor on the top of the screen. A menu should appear with the options `File`, `Edit`, etc. There you can follow the instructions. It's also possible from terminal, and I suggest you read here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine. But I'd rather go with the GUI tool. If you try this in the console, you would need to look for mirrors manually: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like your software source is CD/DVD... you should probably want to use the internet. Open Ubuntu Software Center, then place your mouse cursor on the top of the screen. A menu should appear with the options File, Edit, etc. Click Edit >> Software Source. In the very first tab you just need to disable the bottom option "install from CD".

[image]

Have a look at the official documentation if you have trouble: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu